# Как в условии UPDATE использовать данные из другой таблицы?

Tags: mysql

Есть примерно такая таблица:

```
----------
Table_1
----------
id:int
value:int
----------
```

Я создаю временную таблицу:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_Table_1 SELECT id, value from Table_1 where value=100;
```

Теперь мне нужно установить в таблице `Table_1` значения `value=200` для всех `id` которые присутствуют в `tmp_Table_1`

```
UPDATE Table_1 set value=200 where id (in tmp_Table_1 ????)
```

Подскажите как дописать условие?

Comment: `id` у вас не уникальный? иначе зачем это городить а не просто `update ...set=100 where 200`. Если нет, то `update tmp join t1 ON (...) set t1.value = ...`

Comment: А почему не просто ```UPDATE Table_1 SET value=200 WHERE value=100```? Без всяких временных таблиц.

Comment: Мне нужна временная таблица, что бы после записи вернуть все обратно
id - уникальный

Comment: Чё так сложно-то? ```UPDATE Table_1 set value=200 where value=100;```

Comment: @akina А теперь все записи которые были изменены нужно вернуть обратно

Comment: Другой вопрос == новая тема.

Comment: ответ @teran подошел - через join заработало как надо